# Paypal express payout error SetExpressCheckout failed: Could not resolve host: api-3t(6)

Tags: php, curl, paypal, express-checkout

I am trying to test paypal express checkout with a tutorial I found.

I am working with php on my local pc.

I am using Firefox to test.

When calling paypal, I get this error back:
SetExpressCheckout failed: Could not resolve host: api-3t(6)

I tried a solution from a post here that says: switching nameservers to Google Public DNS at 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

That didn't help

My code:

```
$API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t/".$GLOBALS['paypal_mode'].".paypal.com/nvp";
    $version = urlencode('124.0');

    // Set the curl parameters.
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

    // Turn off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    // Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
    $nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature$nvpStr_";


    // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

    // Get response from the server.
    $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);
```

Can someone please help?

Thank you

Comment: The problem is in your host name. Do `echo $API_Endpoint;` before `$ch = curl_init();` to see the host link.

Comment: Hi Hassan, the echo shows the right host name:(https://api-3t/sandbox.paypal.com/nvp)

Comment: Please check out my answer.

Comment: Oh sorry, only saw your answer below. Issue fixed, thank you very much.!

Comment: what is error now? just copy page once from my answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current host is `api-3t/sandbox.paypal.com/nvp` which is in correct. Correct host is `https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp`

Change from

```
$API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t/".$GLOBALS['paypal_mode'].".paypal.com/nvp";
```

To

```
$API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.".$GLOBALS['paypal_mode'].".paypal.com/nvp";
```